# Check if function called with particular keyword

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

I'm wondering what is the best (most pythonic and/or elegant) way to have operations done on a keyword argument only if it is called. Something like:

```
import keyword

def (*arg, **kwargs):
    if keyword.iskeyword(parameter):
        # Do stuff involving parameter

    # Do other stuff
    return 0
```

Comment: I fail to understand what you mean. Can you clarify things a bit more? E.g. add an example of what's supposed to happen in which cases.

Comment: What is parameter? Why do you want to pass keywords around?

Comment: I want to have the option of passing a keyword argument I call "parameter" to my function. If the function is not called with this kwarg then I don't want to do anything more. But if it is called it is because it will be used by the things inside my function and so I need a method of checking this. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jack not really, but I think chepner's answer is what you're after

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. Are you confusing python keywords with keyword arguments?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes that may be the case.

Comment: Well, kwargs is a dictionary, so all you have to do is check if 'parameter' is in kwargs. Which is really basic python

Comment: Yes agreed. I just wanted to know if thats the preferred way of doing it and i got mixed up with the terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the expected key is in the `kwargs` argument:

```
def foo(*arg, **kwargs):
    if 'bar' in kwargs:
        print('You called foo with bar={}'.format(kwargs['bar']))
    else:
        print('You didn't use the "bar" keyword argument')
```